# Pyspark pass column expression inside another expression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that generates a column expression based on some arguments. Below is some example.

```py
def apply_operator(operator:str):
   return F.expr(f"filter(col1,lambda x: x {operator} 3)")
```

I now want to pass this expression into another expression, and tried something like the following.

```py
F.expr(f"case when {apply_operator("<")} then this else that end")
```

This throws an error. How can I extract an expression and then pass to another expression?

I tried something similar to what is mentioned above and got the error that I cannot pass a `column<>` in expr.

Comment: `expr()` accepts string, but your `apply_operator` function returns an expression. you can just return the string without the `expr()` if needed